# Why useEffect not updating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

The structure of my application is :

When the user clicks on **StartQuiz**  button in`<Home>`  component,he is directed to the `'/quiz'` route. `<Quiz>`  component is rendered after that.

My `<Quiz>` component is supposed to get the questions from the App component but is not getting that. `<App>`  component gets the questions from the `<Home>` Component..

The Code is as follows:

Home.js file:

```
 import ErrorMessage from '../errormessage';

const Home = (props) => {
  const {name,setName,fetchQuestions}=props;
  const [category,setCategory]=useState("");
  const [difficulty,setDifficulty]=useState("");
  const [error,setError]=useState(false);
  const history=useNavigate();
  const handlesubmit=()=>{
    if(!category || !name || !difficulty)
     setError(true);
    else
     {
       fetchQuestions(category,difficulty);
       history('/quiz')                //pushes it in the quiz route
     }
  }
  return (
  <div className="content">
      <div className="settings">
          <span style={{fontSize:30}}>Quiz Settings</span>
      </div>
      <div className="settingsselect">
        {error && <ErrorMessage></ErrorMessage>}
        <TextField label="Enter Your Name" variant="outlined" onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} value={name}/>
        <TextField id="outlined-select-currency" select label="Select Category" variant="outlined" onChange={(e)=>setCategory(e.target.value)} value={category}>
         {
           Categories.map((cat)=>{
             return(
           <MenuItem key={cat.category}  value={cat.value}>{cat.category}</MenuItem>);
          })
         }
        </TextField>
        <TextField  select label="Select Difficulty" onChange={(e)=>setDifficulty(e.target.value)} value={difficulty}>
          <MenuItem label="Easy" value="easy">Easy</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem label="Medium" value="medium">Medium</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem label="Hard" value="hard">Hard</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handlesubmit}>Start Quiz</Button>
      </div>
      <img src="question.svg" className="banner"></img>
  </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

App.js file:

```
 const [questions,setQuestions]=useState();
    useEffect(()=>{
      console.log("Questions have changed");
    },[questions]);
    const fetchQuestions=async(category,difficulty)=>{
       const {data}=await axios(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=${category}&difficulty=${difficulty}&type=multiple`);
       setQuestions(data.results);
    }
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
     <div className="App" style={{backgroundImage: "url(./ques1.png)"}}>
      <Header/>
       <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" exact element={<Home name={name} setName={setName} fetchQuestions={fetchQuestions}/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/quiz" exact element={<Quiz name={name} questions={questions} score={score} setScore={setScore} />}></Route>
       </Routes>
      <Footer></Footer>
     </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Quiz.js file:

```
const Quiz = (props) => {
  

  const {name,questions,score,setScore}=props;
  const [options,setOptions]=useState();
  const [currentQuestion,setCurrentQuestion]=useState(0);
  
 
  return (
  <div className='quiz'>
    <span className="subtitle">Welcome ,{name}</span>
    <div className="questionInfo">
      <Question questions={questions} currentQuestion={currentQuestion} setCurrentQuestion={setCurrentQuestion} options={options}/>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
};

export default Quiz;
```

But Im getting `undefined` when doing `console.log(questions)` in the `<Quiz>` component..

please figure out the issue..

Comment: You never run `f1`.

Comment: @tkausl I have made the edits but still it shows undefined

Comment: In the App.js, can you check console.log(data.results) in fetchQuestions?

Comment: where do you get `history` from ? is it props or ?

Comment: @CyrusZei it is in the Quiz ```Home``` component itself.

Comment: @BK52 I added a log statement at App..```data.results``` gives the set of questions but  ```questions``` gives undefined.

Comment: yes, I see that it is in the `Home` but where are you getting that from? Where does `history comes from ?`

Comment: @CyrusZei I have made edits so that the entire **Home.js** file is now shown.

Comment: @VatsalAMehta let's make it easy why don't you fetch data directly from quiz component instead of app component

Comment: when users visits the /quiz route then only you need to show your quiz questions then why are you fetching on home page

Comment: try to put initial Questions on the before loading from the server to see if you see those questions??? by the way `fetchQuestions` function never get called because its not on the `useEffect`

Comment: No, `fetchQuestions` gets called on `handleSubmit` got you @Vatsal A Mehta

Comment: when you hit `handleSubmit` the console on `useEffect` is supposed to execute `console.log("Questions have changed");` as you have putted, does it get executed?? because that signify that `questions` variable get changed, i.e we got new questions from the server

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal I added that at homepage because questions to be displayed when user clicks on the StartQuiz button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `fetchQuestions(category,difficulty)` in `handleSubmit` you need to await it there as well.

The await inside `fetchQuestions` does not extend outside of the function, so making `handleSubmit` async as well will properly await before navigating

```js
// Home

const handlesubmit = async () => {
  if(!category || !name || !difficulty) {
    setError(true);
  } else {
    await fetchQuestions(category,difficulty);
    history('/quiz')              
  }
}
```

Next, in Quiz you will need `useState()` and `useEffect()` to respond to the change of props.questions.

```js
// Quiz

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const Quiz = (props) => {

  const [questionsDisplay, setQuestionsDisplay] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const display = props.questions.map((q,idx) => (<div key={idx}>{q.question}</div>))
    setQuestionsDisplay(display)
  }, [props.questions])

  return (
  <div className='quiz'>
    <span className="subtitle">Welcome ,{name}</span>
    <div className="questionInfo">
      {questionsDisplay}
    </div>
  </div>
  );
};

export default Quiz;
```